# Cypher Query to calculate Jaccard Similarity

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running this query from the neo4j-shell and I can't understand why it does not finish. It should compute the Jaccard similarity between two journals which have the same authors publishing on them.

The query is the following:

```
MATCH (j1:JOURNAL), (j2:JOURNAL)
WHERE id(j1) > id(j2)
WITH j1, j2
OPTIONAL MATCH common=(j1)<-[:PUBLISHED_ON]-(art1:ARTICLE)
<-[:WRITES]-(a:AUTHOR)-[:WRITES]->(art2:ARTICLE)-[:PUBLISHED_ON]->(j2)
WITH j1, j2,  COUNT(common) as intersection
OPTIONAL MATCH (j1)<-[:PUBLISHED_ON]-(art1:ARTICLE)<-[:WRITES]-(a:AUTHOR)
WITH j1, j2, intersection, COLLECT(DISTINCT a.id_author) AS t1s
OPTIONAL MATCH (j2)<-[:PUBLISHED_ON]-(art2:ARTICLE)<-[:WRITES]-(a:AUTHOR)
WHERE NOT a IN t1s
WITH j1, j2, intersection, t1s + COLLECT(DISTINCT a.id_author) AS union

RETURN j1, j2, (intersection*1.0) / size(union)*100 as js

ORDER BY js desc;
```

Has anyone idea why it does not finish? Is this correct?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A fist idea is to use LIMIT (lets say LIMIT 1) and supress the ORDER BY to see if it returns something. If it does, then there is some performance issue. If it does not...clearly there is some problem in the query

Comment: I added LIMIT 2 and suppressed the ORDER BY, but it does not return errors or syntax problems. Actually, it does not return anything, just continues to work.
I can't see the problem or the issue in my query; I am running it from neo4j-shell on a server.

Comment: How big is the database - are we talking about thousand or millions of nodes?

Comment: It has about 12 millions nodes

Comment: I only spent 2 minutes reading on the subject, so take this with a grain of salt: it seems that to accurately determine the Jaccard index, the complexity of the algorithm is quadratic w.r.t. the size of the set. This shows from your query: you start by creating a Cartesian product of journals - so if you have _n_ journals, your query starts by generating _n_^2 rows. This is already quote a lot, and the rest of the query - which will be evaluated for each row - is also quite complex. Is using another similarity metric or an approximation of the Jaccard index acceptable for your use case?

Comment: I can probably find another measure for the similarity, but I have the same problem with another query which calculates the centrality (aka the importance in the database) of every article.

There is a way to avoid the cartesian products of the journals or to improve the efficiency of this query?
Thanks for your help, it is the first time I use cypher.

Comment: Graph analytics is a use case that is *not* a good fit for Cypher. I did quite a lot of work in both graph pattern matching and graph analytics - you can express similarity/centrality metrics with Cypher but they will be slow for large graphs. I created a GraphGist on the topic a couple of month ago: http://portal.graphgist.org/graph_gists/1b9df3bc-5b01-47d3-8c37-ddff30c5c08d (the queries are more accessible here: https://gist.github.com/szarnyasg/80d0994a1930390b9da66fc7793b55d8). But the point of this demo is only that you can express these metrics in Cypher.

Comment: Bottom line: if you want to calculate graph analytics, you should avoid Cypher and use dedicated global graph processing technologies, such as Spark (which can read from Neo4j using the [Mazerunner library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mazerunner), Flink or Giraph. Cypher is a great and expressive language, but it's primary use case is pattern matching and not global graph analytics.

Comment: In the meantime, I distilled my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your query will execute slowly because it creates a Cartesian product of journals, which means that for n journals, it will process n^2 rows during the query.

Graph analytics is a use case that is not a good fit for Cypher. You can express similarity/centrality metrics with Cypher but they will be slow for large graphs. If your primary goal is to perform graph analytics, you should avoid Cypher and use dedicated global graph processing technologies, such as Spark (which can read from Neo4j using the [Mazerunner](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mazerunner) library), [Flink](https://flink.apache.org/) or [Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org/). Cypher is a great and expressive language, but its primary use case is pattern matching and not global graph analytics.

While you can use more efficient technologies (e.g. that are better suited for graph analytics and utilize multiple CPU core), calculating the Jaccard index will always require n^2 steps. So you may also want to use another similarity metrics or approximations that are quicker to evaluate.